In Raydium ammConfig accounts, what does the index represent
For example in Raydium CPMM program, what does index represent?
I derived three accounts with indexes being 1, 2 and 3  and all were valid accounts
Here is how the account is initialized in the code https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-clmm/blob/119ed36bf9f33335ed8d671780502bc37d9f1605/programs/amm/src/instructions/admin/create_amm_config.rs#L17-L27
// ---- snip
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [
            AMM_CONFIG_SEED.as_bytes(),
            &index.to_be_bytes()
        ],
        bump,
        payer = owner,
        space = AmmConfig::LEN
    )]
    pub amm_config: Account<'info, AmmConfig>,
// --- snip

